# Sudo tickets and subsequent non-sudo sibling process

Tags: linux, permissions, security, sudo, root

Imagine that locally on my system `sudo` is configured with a timeout, so that once I authenticate after running `sudo` once in some terminal, I don't need to re-authenticate for another 10 minutes.

Does this effectively give processes running as children of the process that *invoked `sudo`, but not with `sudo` themselves* (hence as **siblings, not children** of the process that was run *with* `sudo`) the ability to escalate their privileges to root?

As a concrete example, imagine I run, in the terminal:

```
sudo echo "hi"
other_process
```

The `echo` process is run with `sudo`, but `other_process` is not. Can `other_process` use the 10-minute-expiry sudo ticket associated with the earlier `sudo` call, e.g., by itself launching a sub-process via `sudo`?

I guess if the answer is yes, it means you need to be very careful with any processes that you run within the timeout period of `sudo`. One might imagine that running an untrusted process like `other_process` would keep it within the sandbox of the current user, but if it can use the existing `sudo` ticket it could escalate to root.

Does the answer change if the `sudo` invocation comes not directly in the terminal but in a script launched from the terminal?

E.g., I run:

```
script.sh
other_process2
```

If inside `script.sh`, there is a line like `sudo echo "inside script"`, will other processes subsequently launched by the script be able to use the sudo ticket to escalate their privileges to root? How about after the script finishes: will other processes in the terminal that ran `script.sh` still be able to use the `sudo` ticket<sup>1</sup>?

---

<sup>1</sup> These are no longer like sibling but somehow 'aunt' or 'uncle' processes (siblings of the parent).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the sudo ticket is good for any process running in that terminal (at least running as your user). This is easy enough to test. Just make a `test.sh` (or whatever) with:

```shell
#!/bin/sh

sudo apt-get check
```

Then:

```
$ sudo apt-get check
[sudo] password for anthony: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

$ ./test.sh 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

Generally, it's not advisable to run non-trusted programs, especially as your user. And you certainly shouldn't do it on a terminal you've got a sudo ticket for. If you must run non-trusted programs, you ought to set up security barriers (at minimum a different user, but even better would be a VM, or at least a container — setting up a secure sandbox for running untrusted programs is non-trivial).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Because `sudo` authorization is tied to a combination of your username and tty and a timestamp, any commands run from that shell could conceivably pass along the ability to themselves elevate privileges via sudo without typing your password (assuming you don't have `timestamp_timeout=0` in your `/etc/sudoers` file).

As long as those scripts are executed within whatever timeout you do have set (default = 15 minutes).

file test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "test: \$SHLVL is: $SHLVL"
echo "test: I am $(id) on $(tty)"
echo "test: with sudo I am $(sudo id) on $(tty)"
/bin/bash -l ./sudotest.sh
```

file sudotest.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "sudotest: \$SHLVL is: $SHLVL"
echo "sudotest: I am $(id) on $(tty)"
echo "sudotest: with sudo I am $(sudo id) on $(tty)"
```

results in:

```
test: $SHLVL is: 2
test: I am uid=1000(tim) gid=1000(tim) groups=1000(tim) on /dev/pts/7
[sudo] password for tim:
test: with sudo I am uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) on /dev/pts/7
sudotest: $SHLVL is: 3
sudotest: I am uid=1000(tim) gid=1000(tim) groups=1000(tim) on /dev/pts/7
sudotest: with sudo I am uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) on /dev/pts/7
```

In that case, the first call to sudo was in `test.sh`, but `sudotest.sh` was **not** called with sudo itself, however because my username and tty are still the same, sudo recognized that process as being eligible for elevated privileges and didn't prompt me for a password during the execution of `sudotest.sh`.

And if I run it again after a couple of minutes, but before the timeout:

```
test: $SHLVL is: 2
test: I am uid=1000(tim) gid=1000(tim) groups=1000(tim) on /dev/pts/7
test: with sudo I am uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) on /dev/pts/7
sudotest: $SHLVL is: 3
sudotest: I am uid=1000(tim) gid=1000(tim) groups=1000(tim) on /dev/pts/7
sudotest: with sudo I am uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) on /dev/pts/7
```

I don't get prompted at all.  And I wouldn't until the `timestamp_timeout` time limit passes.

You can see that the tty is staying the same throughout executions, and that `SHLVL` is incrementing because each shell process that's executed by the script is a level deeper from the calling shell.  My interactive shell, `SHLVL = 1`, calls `test.sh` which gets `SHLVL = 2`, which calls `sudotest.sh` which gets `SHLVL = 3`.

One possible caveat to this is if you have an older version of sudo, where the `tty_tickets` option is not set, which removes the username+tty granularity for sudo sessions, and limits granularity only to username and timestamp.

Other `sudoers` options could potentially have an impact, too, like `requiretty`.

As long as subsequent calls to `sudo` from scripts called by the original shell are issued within the time limit on sudo credential retention, they will be able to elevate as the same user.  Once the time limit is up, they'll need to have a way to re-enter the password if you want them to be able to continue elevating privileges.  (or you could change the timeout, or disable password requirements for a user, or a command... but those are out of scope for this answer).

Answer (score -2):

The answer is no. Try `sudo id` followed by `id` to verify.

Comment: The question isn't whether subsequent processes run as root automatically (obviously not), but whether they can use the `sudo` ticket to do so. So this test doen't show much beyond that the second `id` doens't run as root by default (this wasn't in question). You'd want a the second process to internally exec `sudo` to get a good test (hint: on the systems I've tried any other process launched in the same terminal _can_ escalate to root via the sudo ticket). I tried to make this clear in the question, but if some part can be clarified, please let me know!

Comment: @BeeOnRope You're right, I misread the question. The answer is actually yes. Create a bash script containing the single command `sudo id`. If you run that script you'll see that it does used the cached ticket to elevate privs.